# How to interpret fixed effects model when the fixed effects uniquely identifies each observation?

Tags: regression, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Say I have a dataset that is uniquely identified by country and year. Then, I run a fixed effects regression with country and year fixed effects. How do I interpret the result of the regression coefficient? Surely I cannot say that it is the average correlation of X on Y controlling for countries and years, because each country and each year uniquely identify my observations!
And yet commands such as `areg` in STATA claim that they are able to do just that. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something. Somebody please help.

Comment: country $\times$ year is not the same as country AND year FEs.

Comment: I am interested in the latter. I do understand that the former would also uniquely identify all my observations, but doesn't the latter as well?

Comment: No, compare what you get with `webuse pig, clear
reg weight i.id i.week 
reg weight i.id##i.week `

Comment: I see you're trying to point out that if I added country AND year FEs, then there would still be degrees of freedom available to estimate standard errors. but how am I to interpret the coefficient, especially when both country and year FEs are present as well? the effect of X on Y, controlling for year and country (i.e. if I were to add country FEs, then I would interpret it as "the effect of X on Y within country Z", but with BOTH year and country FEs, I could not say "the effect of X on Y within country Z and year T", because Z and T uniquely identify X and Y...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected value in your model is

$$E[y_i \vert x_i,c_i,t]=\beta \times x_i + \gamma_{ci}+ \eta_t $$

You can think of the $\gamma_{ci}$ as a country-specific intercept that does not vary across time. It captures all the time-invariant factors for each country (like longitude). $\eta_t$ is a time effect that is constant across countries but is not time-invariant (like oil prices). These two effects will shift the y-x curve up or down, leaving the slope with respect to $x$ alone.

The interpretation of $\beta$ is the change in the expected value of $y_i$ associated with a 1 unit increase in $x_i$. In this case, it is the same for all countries and time periods. It's the marginal effect of $x$ adjusting for differences in time-invariant characteristics across countries and for time effects that impact all countries in the same way.

Comment: Thanks dimitriy. Hard to know where cross-validated would be without you.